# While sending courses to backend api, it is coming in loop for many times

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a frontend on vanilla JS, In which i am taking some courses from user and sending them to my backend api but it takes first course for two time and when i select more than 2 courses it repeates first course for two times, second for one and third for three times, I I have tried different things but it didn't work. Can somebody please guide me on this?

```
let courseList1 = []
let courseList = []

addCoursesBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  courseList1.push(dropdownCourses.value)
  // appending on frontend
  let value = courseList1[courseList1.length - 1];
  courseContainer.append(value)

  courseList1.forEach((course, index) => {
    console.log("inside for each")
   let mappedValue = {
      courseName: course
    };
    courseList.push(mappedValue)
    console.log("course list is: " + courseList)
  })

})
form.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
  try {
    e.preventDefault();
    let token = localStorage.getItem("Token")
    let name = inputName.value;
    let phoneNumber = inputPhoneNum.value;
    let cnic = inputCnic.value;
    const body = {
      name, phoneNumber, cnic, courseList
    }
    console.log(body)

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/addStudent", {

      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    const res = await response.json();
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: this happens because you iterate the whole `courseList1` everytime you click the `addCoursesBtn` button: `courseList1.forEach((course, index) => {`

Comment: remove the `forEach` loop and leave only `let mappedValue = { courseName: dropdownCourses.value }; courseList.push(mappedValue)`